# Should I use "controllers" or "directives" when loading templates and creating a scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, controllers

Let me give two examples to better explain my confusion:

## HTML1

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="template1" ng-controller="controller1">
    </ng-include>
</div>
<div>
    <ng-include src="template2" ng-controller="controller2">
    </ng-include>
</div>
```

## HTML2

```
<div>
    <templateone-include src="template1">
    </templateone-include>
</div>
<div>
    <templatetwo-include src="template2">
    </templatetwo-include>
</div>
```

As you can see here I am providing two ways to load different templates.

1. Using **ng-include** and assigning a controller to create a scope.
2. Using a directive which will load templates(using templateUrl) and create an isolated scope.

I usually think that directives are mainly used for DOM manipulations and for reusable code and controllers for different sections with different data and hence I would use 1st approach and not 2nd is because the sole purpose of us using the different directives is to load different templates and create an isolated scope.

So which according to you is better and proper approach?

Comment: ng-include is a directive, if you are creating a directive to emulate ng-include without adding anything to it you are re-inventing the wheel. Directives don't necessarily need to have isolated scopes

Comment: @Luis please see the edit and reply to my comment below

Comment: I stand by my comment...if you only need to import a template then use ng-include directive why on earth are you developing a directive which functionality is exactly the same as ng-include? if you want to do anything more than what ng-includes offer then yes you will need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I usually think that directives are mainly used for DOM manipulations
>   and for reusable code and controllers for different sections with
>   different data and hence I would use 1st approach and not 2nd is
>   because the sole purpose of us using the different directives is to
>   load different templates and create an isolated scope.

This is also my opinion on directives. Directives should be used to add some behaviour to some particular HTML elements. If you just need to include a template and link it to a controller, the first option is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I didnt remove ng-controller from custom directives in 2nd approach code .I meant to say the custom directives creates an isolated scope.So now which approach should i use?

Comment: The first one is still a "regular" angular approach. The 2nd one looks like a workaround.